# Reverse history search in bash followed by arrow keys causes cursor to display at the wrong location

Tags: bash

I've noticed that many times when I'm reverse-history-searching from the command line via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, if I want to edit the command, sometimes the cursor jumps to the wrong position when I press an arrow key or enter <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>. The specific position it jumps to seems to be an offset equal to the size of my command line prompt as set in `PS1`.

This causes difficulty because the actual location of the cursor is different from what is rendered on the screen; future edits to the command are rendered as if the cursor is where it jumped to, but the actual command retains the correct location without any jump.

Does anyone know what's causing this or how to fix it?

EDIT: If I add a newline at the end of `PS1` the problem seems to go away. However, I would prefer to enter the command on the same line as the prompt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is often caused by commands in your history that are longer than 1 line. When you select a shorter item out of the history it doesn't seem to take into account the width of the prompt in re-rendering the command line, so everything after that long command is screwy.

The easy solution I've found is to hit the home key, insert "echo " and hit enter. Then recall the last command and edit from there. (First removing the echo. :)

**SEE ALSO alexander-somov's answer below which identifies a way to fix the most common cause of this issue.**

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried that just a little while ago. In my case I was careless and blew away a file because there was a pipe in the command that swallowed the echo. You are correct, this seems to only affect long commands according to my experimentation.

Comment: A better solution than echo that I just found: Append a '#' to the beginning of the line rather than an echo. This way bash treats the whole line like a comment.

Comment: Yet better: the problem seems to go away if the current line is redrawn. Either C-l to clear screen and redraw current line or creating a key binding for the unbound function redraw-current-line.

Comment: I forgot to mention the C-l solution as I really hate losing the scroll buffer, but yes, it's a temporary rendering glitch from the history navigation, so forcing a redraw will fix it. redraw-current-line sounds like an even better solution!

Answer (score 16):

Maybe you have non-printing escape sequences in PS1 not enclosed in \[ and \].

Be sure that you enclosed all of them like this:

```
\[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[31m\] $ \[\e[0m\]
```

Comment: Works great if you enclose only the non-printing sequences in `\[` and `\]` (so you need multiple groups of these block quotes)

Comment: Could more detail be added to this answer? I don't understand the example because I can see \[ and \] in that too. A before/after comparison would be helpful!